# VBA - Hide sheet if cell is = "empty"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large workbook, I would like to have a macro that when run will hide sheets where cell n3 = "empty", if n3="Ok" or " " do nothing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop going through all worksheets in the workbook and check for the cell value. If condition met then set the `Visible` property of that worksheet to `xlSheetHidden`.